# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'UseState')

Tags: reactjs, jsx, mern

I am getting 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'UseState')' error. I am trying to delete the row on click on delete icon/button. And my userRows data is in different file (import { userRows } from '../../dummydata';). I have attached screenshot for error message. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFUig.png)

userList.jsx :-

```
import './userlist.css';
import { userRows } from '../../dummydata';
import DeleteOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeleteOutline';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { React } from "react";

export default function userlist() {
    const [data, setData] = React.UseState(userRows);

    const handleDelete = (id) => {
        setData(data.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
    };
    const columns = [
        { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 100 },
        {
            field: 'username', headerName: 'User', width: 200, renderCell: (params) => {
                return (
                    <div className='userListUser'>
                        <img className='userListImg' src={params.row.avatar} alt="" />
                        {params.row.username}
                    </div>
                )
            }
        },
        { field: 'email', headerName: 'Email', width: 200 },
        {
            field: 'status',
            headerName: 'Status',
            width: 200,
        },
        {
            field: 'transaction',
            headerName: 'Transaction Volume',
            width: 200,
        },
        {
            field: 'action',
            headerName: 'Action',
            width: 150,
            renderCell: (params) => {
                return (
                    <>
                        <Link to={"/user/" + params.row.id}>
                            <button className='userListEdit'>Edit</button>
                        </Link>
                        <DeleteOutlineIcon className='userListDelete' onClick={() => handleDelete(params.row.id)} />
                    </>
                )
                console.log(params.row.id);
            }
        },
    ];
    return (
        <div className='userList'>
            <DataGrid
                rows={data} disableSelectionOnClick
                columns={columns}
                pageSize={8}
                rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
                checkboxSelection
            />
        </div>
    )
}


App.js:-
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Topbar />
      <div className="nav-container">
        <Sidebar />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/users" element={<UserList />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The `u` in `useState` is lower case.

Comment: Is `React` a named export from `'react'`?  I've only ever seen it used as the default export.

Answer (score 4):

The first issue is that the `u` in `UseState` is lowercase, replace it with `useState`.
The second issue is that `react` is not imported correctly.
Either use `import {useState} from 'react'` or `import React from 'react'` or `import * as React from 'react'`

Comment: I tried below changes-

import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';


export default function userlist() {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(userRows);

But getting error as - 
React Hook "React.useState" is called in function "userlist" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter

Answer (score 0):

I personally would follow 1 of 2 different approaches here. Could be worth considering:

1.
If I were you I would bring the data for userRows into this component by passing a prop (or by prop drilling).

e.g.

```
import { useState } from "react"

export default function userlist({userRows}) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(userRows);
```

**or**

2.
I would bring in userRows via the context hook.

```
import UserContext from '../../utils/UserContext'
import { useContext } from 'react'

export default function userlist() {
   const { userRows } = useContext(UserContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue. My file name should be 'UserList' instead of 'userlist'. First letter of file name needs to be capital.

Thanks Guys, for Support!!